# Measure Theory Excercise

Tags: measure-theory

I'm taking a course of measure theory applied to probability, and I'm asked to prove the following:

$X$ is a random variable. If $E[e^{-X^2}]=1$, calculate the distribution of $X$.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$
E(e^{-X^2})=\int_\Omega e^{-X(\omega)^2}dP(\omega).
$$
Since $e^{-X^2}\leq 1$, and $P(\Omega)=1$ since $\Omega$ is a probability space, we see that $E(e^{-X^2})=1$ if and only if $e^{-X^2}=1$ with probability $1$. This happens if and only if $X=0$ with probabilty $1$. Therefoer you can calculate the distribution function of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for any real number $x$, we have $e^{-x^2} \le 1$, with equality if and only if $x=0$. Show that if $P(X = 0) < 1$, then $E[e^{-X^2}] < 1$.